# Why my jquery plugin doesn't working?

Tags: jquery

I am making a plug-in, but i am not getting any result, if i put console inside the function, in case if i place it out it works.

what is the issue? any one can help me to find out?

my code :

```
(function ($){
    $.fn.slideIt = function () {
        this.fadeOut('normal', function(){
            console.log(this);
        });

}
})(jQuery);
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RW8R3/)

Answer (score 1):

Your jsFiddle was made incorrectly.  The HTML box should only contain HTML, put  your JavaScript in the `JavaScript` box.

The problem was, you were calling `slideIt` before it was declared.

Here's an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/RW8R3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use document ready event, your div not exist when your call plugin:

```
$(function(){
    $('#slideContainer').slideIt();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RW8R3/2/

Answer (score 0):

You're breaking "the magic of jQuery". The plugin should look like this:

```
(function($) 
{
    $.fn.slideIt = function()
    {
        return this.each(function()
        {
            $(this).fadeOut('normal', function()
            {
                console.log($(this));
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

$('#slideContainer').slideIt();​
```

Otherwise you wouldn't be able to do things like $('#slideContainer').slideIt().fadeIn("slow").

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RW8R3/4/).